# What is the purpose of configname setting in SolrCloud

Tags: solr

Say when you're setting up Zookeeper such as `java -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/foobar/conf -Dhost=127.0.0.1:9983 -Dcollection.configName=myconf -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -jar start.jar`

What is configName used for? There is no file name that. I don't know where this label is used.

Answer (score 2):

`configName` refers to the name of the configuration file set to be uploaded.

If you pass `bootstrap_confdir=<directory>` on startup, that specific directory of configuration files will be uploaded to ZooKeeper with a `conf.set` name *defined* by `collection.configName`.

`collection.configName` *determines* the name under which that configuration information is stored by ZooKeeper, and corresponds to the name of the `conf.set` pointed to by `bootstrap_confdir` (defaults to `"configuration1"`). "myconf" is an example, it can be anything you'd like.

Here some links that might be useful :
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble
- http://systemsarchitect.net/painless-guide-to-solr-cloud-configuration/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities